# Vue Router 4 path with same name gets overwritten

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

Currently I have setup a dynamic path for `/gallery/:id` that works fine. But now the children path of `/admin/gallery` doesn't load anymore. Only when I remove the dynamic one again.

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/admin",
    name: "admin",
    meta: {
      title: "Admin Panel",
      enforceLogin: true,
    },
    redirect: "/admin/welcome",
    component: () => import("@/views/AdminView.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "welcome",
        name: "welcome",
        meta: {
          title: "Admin Panel",
          enforceLogin: true,
        },
        component: () => import("@/views/admin/WelcomeInfo.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "gallery",
        name: "gallery",
        meta: {
          title: "Galerie Administration",
          enforceLogin: true,
        },
        component: () => import("@/views/admin/GalleryAdministration.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/gallery/:id",
    name: "gallery",
    meta: {
      title: "Galerie",
    },
    component: () => import("@/views/GalleryView.vue"),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

I've also created a new vue-cli project and tested it there, still doesn't seem to work. I've noticed something weird while testing. If I move the `/gallery/:id` above the `/admin` route, the `/admin/gallery` route works again. So I think the route that comes first, gets overwritten.

### How to reproduce

I've created a small guide for reproduction [here](https://gist.github.com/Nevah5/5453df59d5b7c6315c85afe103ecb227).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router path names are unique.

So in my case renaming `/admin/gallery` to `/admin/gallery-managment` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rename the route whose path is `/gallery/:id`?

I guess Vue-router might be confused because there are two different paths with the same name.

Comment: Good point, I've tried that, definitely works, but I don't want to rename it. why is the router even confused? I beg I am making some kind of syntax mistake…

Comment: Honestly, I don't know exactly why. But you can do like this, you can add "admin-" prefix to child paths. For example, "admin-welcome", "admin-gallery"...

Comment: I checked, renaming `/gallery/:id` doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you are using RouterView? Because the RouterView you are using for the children renders only the children. You should use another RouterView for parent routes. Because when you replace "`/gallery/:id` with `/gallery-test/:id`" it didn't work either.

Comment: I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L77Uq93XXzk), could it be that something got messed up in the project? Everything works, so I don't think I did something wrong.
I've also tried the dynamic route with a new vue-cli project and it looks like this also doesn't work. I will edit the question above soon and write down what I've tried in the new project.

Comment: I've created an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1596) now on vue-router its github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with vue-router-4 but Could it be because of this line?

```
redirect: "/admin/welcome",
```

Comment: No, because all the admin paths are working when I remove `/gallery/:id`